# execute in remote machine from a shell script in local machine

Tags: terminal

1. shell script should be on local machine.
2. shell script contain two steps 
   a. ssh command along with password 
   b. sudo command along with password.
3. i cannot install any packages not allowed.

Please help me how to write command inside shell script.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What you want to execute in remote machine?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ssh user@server_ip "bash -s" < script.sh
```

Comment: I am trying to logging in and get data from server using local machine shell script.

Comment: We have two step of verification first ssh i am able to looging in but second sudo is not executing from shell script

Comment: ssh user@server_ip "bash -s" < script.sh -- didn't worked only ssh command executed and next shell script didn't executed.

Answer (score 0):

using send and expect commands correctly issue fixed for me. Thank you for suggestions